# GitLab CI - Use specific keyword in jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with GitLab CI (maybe I try to use it in the wrong way).
I have templates with artifacts and jobs that are used templates with artifacts but the value `expire_in` should be used only on a specific branch e.g.

template:

```yaml
.build_template: &artifactsTMP
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - test.py
        expire_in: 3 minutes
```

jobs

```yaml
firstJob:
  stage: build
  <<: *artifactsTMP
  script:
      - echo "sth"
  rules:
    - If: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"

secondJob:
  stage: build
  <<: *artifactsTMP
  script:
      - echo "sth"
```

What I want to do is that `expire_in` should be run only on branch "dev".
I tried to use the `IF` statement inside `artifacts` and `rules` but it was not working.
Is there any option to add the `expire_in` during `job` execution?

For example:

template:

```yaml
.build_template: &artifactsTMP
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - test.py
```

jobs:

```yaml
firstJob:
  stage: build
  <<: *artifactsTMP
  script:
      - echo "sth"
  rules:
    - If: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"

secondJob:
  stage: build
  <<: *artifactsTMP
  >>ADD HERE expire_in: 5 minutes<<
  script:
      - echo "sth"
```

Is there any change to do that or just simply I should create two templates, one without `expire_in` second with `expire_in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this could be variablizing the expire_in value and pass it accordingly for your respective branches like below,

template:

```
.build_template: &artifactsTMP
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - test.py
        expire_in: $EXPIRY_TIME
```

and you can create 2 jobs for dev and non dev, where the EXPIRY_TIME value can be passed as a variable,

```
firstJobDev:
  stage: build
  <<: *artifactsTMP
  variables:
     EXPIRY_TIME: 0 minutes
  script:
      - echo "sth"
  only:
    - yourBranchName
```

Create similar job as shown above for non dev branches

Comment: Unfortunately this option not working.
The error occurs when the pipeline runs

``jobs:firstjobdev:artifacts expire in should be a duration``

I've set the EXPIRY_TIME: 5 minutes

Comment: @Solaire can you once check your gitlab runner version. The variable expansion was introduced an year ago for expire_in.  You may try with latest version
Refer this MR :
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/1893?diff_id=77838365

Comment: To be honest it is a really strange situation because I've used github.com and the runner is GitLab runner (I'm not hosting it). Maybe there is an option to set the latest runner or something like that (I'm not good at GitLab CI/CD) :)